# Search for classes that implement specific interface and execute a method

Tags: c#, class, methods, interface

I want to call a method that is in classes that implement some specific interface.

I have tried and searched a lot but can't  get out what to do.
This is my idear about but it is not working.

Hope someone can help me.

```
// getting the list
List<Type> instances =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(a => a.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISearchThisInterface))).ToList();

foreach (Type instance in instances)
{
  // here I want to execute the method of the classes that implement the interface
  (instance as ISearchThisInterface).GetMyMethod(); 
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you have to do here:

- Find types implementing the interface, and
- Instantiate objects of those types

Only after both are done can you invoke a method on instances.

Another important aspect is that all types selected must allow instantiation: they must be non-abstract types, non-generic types, and have parameterless constructor, or otherwise you won't have the way to instantiate them.

If you are aware that you have to create new instances of the type, then this is one possible way:

```
IEnumerable<ISearchThisInterface> instances =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()  // Gets all types
        .Where(type => typeof(ISearchThisInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)) // Ensures that object can be cast to interface
        .Where(type => 
            !type.IsAbstract && 
            !type.IsGenericType &&
            type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]) != null) // Ensures that type can be instantiated
        .Select(type => (ISearchThisInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type)) // Create instances
        .ToList();

foreach (ISearchThisInterface instance in instances)
{
    instance.AMethod();
}
```

Comment: That looks great. unfortunately i will get an exception because the constructor of the class is not empty. But I have diferent classes with different constructors. Is there a way to solve that dynamically?

//here an example
    public class SomeClass : ISomeClass, ISearchThisInterface
    {
        protected readonly IBeAnotherInterface _anotherService;

        public SomeClass (
            IBeAnotherInterface anotherService)
        {
            _anotherService = anotherService);
        }

 //here come some methods for both interfaces
    }

Comment: It is possible to solve that using IoC container which would then resolve types dynamically. It would be much heavier solution than that above and you can try to Google that (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820520/ioc-how-to-create-objects-dynamically). Solution based on `Activator` only works for parameterless constructors.

Comment: If you want to try using IoC container to raise this solution to a new level, then it might be a better idea to open a new question and post the final code which works for parameterless constructors as the starting point. Someone might help with that quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take a look at it.